# How to obtain the HTML source for mysite.master?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, master-page, custom-masterpage

As per [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122692/create-a-custom-master-page-for-a-new-site-collection-by-copy-paste-exsisitng-s), and several others, it's better practice to work with .html files rather than .master files. However, there seems to be no base .html file available for the mysite master.
How would one obtain such a file?

Answer (score 1):

The Design Manager is not available in MySites I don't think. It's this feature that does the stuff with html/master mashups.

Comment: It's true that the design manager is not available in mysites, however, would it still be possible to convert a masterpage backwards, to a html base via manual labor?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The Design Manager stuff converts HTML to master but not the other way round. Even if you did get back to HTML, SharePoint can't do anything with it without Design Manager.